# Show Blogroll of another WordPress site

Tags: query-posts

I am managing a couple of WordPress sites, all hosted on the same VPS, and the client would like the homepage blogroll of `Site A`, that the own, to appear on `Site B` that the also own with the same Author attribution, preferably to link to the originating sites author as opposed to a duped author on `Site B`.

I was thinking of either querying the database on `Site B` with a replica `query_posts()` query however I am having trouble reverse engineering the `query_posts()` function.

Is there a way to do [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#A_Page_of_Posts) for an 'external' site?

NB; sites are not `multisite`. I tried that but it all dropped off and a critical plugin we need is not compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options here, but first let me advise you away from querying the database directly.  If your sites are *that* closely related, then they should be in a Multisite network ...

## RSS

On Site B, fetch the RSS of Site A and display the posts and author attributions there.  You can find [any number of RSS plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=rss) that do this for you or just get you started.

## XML-RPC

Site B can also connect to Site A to fetch the latest posts using [XML-RPC](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support).  You then have full access to data, including the most recent posts, as well as media, comments, etc.

Comment: How is XML-RPC used? Is it called like a function or similar? I can't make heads nor tails of the codex page you linked to?

Comment: Sorry, linked to the wrong Codex page. That was a full description of the API. If you want, I've added a tutorial on [my own site](http://mindsharestrategy.com/2010/wpxmlrpc-using-the-api/) that shows how to actually use it.

Comment: sweet. I'll have a look at that now. Also just a friendly bug-spot; in the bottom code blocks it has `$client-&gt;query` instead of `$client->query`.